How to use the structure "I wish"?

I want to do it when she arrives

I'd like to transform this sentence using "I wish".

I wish I did when when she arrived

I wish I did it when she arrives


Let's go to questions

Is it possible to leave the subordinate clause unchanged or both have to be backshifted?

How to transform this sentence " I want to have done it when she arrives" using "I wish"?



Even setting aside the typo in sentence 2 ("I wish I did it when she arrived"?), none of these sentences are very natural.

Improvising without studying or learning the basics of "wish" when it is used to express regret or desire is a fool's errand. First establish the ground rules, then go and experiment.

Related: Usage of wish for expressing regret and 'I wish I met her now .' Is this correct? and "I wish I knew what was / is wrong with my car" - which is correct?

Your mixing of tenses is producing gibberish.  With to have done it + when she arrives it's anybody's guess what you mean to say.  Are you wishing to have dinner cooked and ready to eat by the time she arrives?

I wish to do it when she arrives.
Wish can also be used of things you would like to do but can't; in that case you would say I wish I could do it when she arrives.

can you say something about my 2 and 3 example? Can 3 be correct?

@Adam 3 cannot be correct, for multiple reasons. I think the sentence you're looking for may be "I hope I have it done when she arrives," or "I hope I've done it by the time she arrives."

I wish I did it cannot be correct. If you would like to have done something in the past that in fact you didn't do, it has to be I wish I had done it. As others have said, combining this with a future event is completely nonsensical.

@KateBunting refering to your example "I wish I could do it when she arrives". If I put there "when she arrived" I also have to change "could" to "could have" and write "I wish I could have done it when you arrived", correct?

Yes, that's right.

Thank you as always
